Adding Squeduled Task to a VM
I'm trying to add a Squeduled Task to my VM, but i keep getting the following error:
- (HRESULT: 0x80070032).
Here is my code for adding the task:
Check if its localy added or remotely:
TaskService tService;
if (server != "" || user != "" || pass != "" || domain != "")
{
    tService = new TaskService(server, user, pass, domain);
}
else
{
    tService = new TaskService();
}

Define Task and add task properties:

TaskDefinition tDefinition = tService.NewTask();
tDefinition.Principal.DisplayName = tskName;
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = tskDesc;
DailyTrigger dtrigger = new DailyTrigger();
dtrigger.StartBoundary = start;
dtrigger.DaysInterval = ((short)repeat);
dtrigger.EndBoundary = end;
dtrigger.Enabled = true;
tDefinition.Triggers.Add(dtrigger);
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Author = PriUtilizador;
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = tskDesc;
tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Date = DateTime.Now;
//this is where i add my action for the task
tDefinition.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("C:\\Users\\goncalo.figueiredo\\PRJ_PRI_ContasCorrentes\\DS.ERP_Primavera_G\\bin\\" + "EmailSender.exe", CCArgs));
if (domain != "")
{
    tDefinition.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount;
    tDefinition.Principal.UserId = "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORKSERVICE";
    tDefinition.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
    try
    {
        tService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(tskName, tDefinition);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
...

Am I on the right track?

I see "EmailSender" in there. 0x80070032 can be a server config issue.  Perhaps try seeing if you can schedule a service that does something benign, like print to console or write to a local file?

EmailSender is a executable that i made that uses SMTP protocol to send emails. I hae found that the main reason this is it can define the task beacuse it has no permissions to acess the server that is given. I am trying to setup a VM to test this
